# How to move An element in an array into a different position while preserving the array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Item 0
    [1] => Item 1   
    [2] =>  Item 2
)
```

Let's say I wanted to move Item 1 to the end of the array and Item 2 to the top of the array (which would push Item 0 to the middle of the array.

How would I do that?

I tried using the unset and splice functions and it works sometimes but advanced movements like the one I talked about above parts of the array get deleted.

Comment: look into array_push, array_pop, and array_shift.  In your example you could do $array = array_unshift(array_pop($array));

Comment: @hackartist: almost, array_unshift takes two arguments and returns something else.

Comment: yep you are right, didn't quite remember it correct but I see your answer got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$end_element = array_pop($arr);
array_unshift($arr, $end_element);
```

Answer (score 0):

For moving `Item 2` to the start, which would implicitly move `Item 1` to the end you can do that in one very simple line:

```
array_unshift($array, array_pop($array));
```

That will take the last element out and afterwards put it back at the beginning.